# trigger function after listening to several triggered events on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I'm using a loader that will wait for angularJs directives to be done and finish.

The reverse is exact too, if my directives finish first the img loader must come after before my page will show.
After that the directives will finish their execution, I'm broadcasting a dom event using angular `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function() {  
   var DirectivesEnded = new Event('DirectivesEnded');
   document.dispatchEvent(DirectivesEnded);
}, 5000);
```

I'm using too a jquery plugin waiting for all img to load.

```
$images = $("img");
imagesLoaded($images).on('done', function (instance, image) {

});
```

after both event have been triggered I want to execute those lines of code making disappear the html layer of the loader.

```
  $(".lazy-load").animate({
    'opacity': 0
  }, 300, "linear", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".lazy-load").hide();
    }, 10);
  });
```

Both of those events and functions are running separately, but my aim is to combine both of them. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: So you want execute what is inside `timeout` after all images are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question well this should do the job:

```
var check_sum = 0;
$timeout(function() {
   var DirectivesEnded = new Event('DirectivesEnded');
   document.dispatchEvent(DirectivesEnded);
   check_sum++;
   finished();
}, 5000);

$images = $("img");
imagesLoaded($images).on('done', function (instance, image) {
    check_sum++;
    finished();
});


function finished() {
  if(check_sum==2) check_sum=0;
  else return;
  $(".lazy-load").animate({
    'opacity': 0
  }, 300, "linear", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".lazy-load").hide();
    }, 10);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution but I'm not able to get checksum from the angular timeout.It is undefined. I ve tried to get it from the window and rootscope and It doesn't exist .
angular.min.js:119 ReferenceError: check_sum is not defined

Comment: @hich_ham i don't know angular at all, you tried saving and getting from window object like that `window.check_sum = 0; // defining` `window.check_sum++; // incrementing` `window.check_sum; // receiving`?

Answer (score 0):

If You only want to show a simple loader before fetching the data, you could simply achieve this by using the angular way, the code could be something like below:

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.loading" ng-include="'assets/templates/loader.tpl.html'"> Loading ... </div>
<div ng-hide="ctrl.loading">Content</div>

//In controller, set ctrl.loading to false after fetching the data.
```